# "Uninitialized constant A::MyModule" error when include MyModule

Tags: ruby

I'm getting this error when trying to use include MyModule "Uninitialized constant"
Here is my implementation:

**a.rb**

```
class A
  include MyModule

  puts ARRAY
end
```

**my_module.rb**

```
module MyModule
  ARRAY = [1,2,3]
end
```

Comment: I cannot reproduce your error. Note the module being included is `B`, not `MyModule`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ruby doesn't know about `MyModule` because it doesn't read `my_module.rb`

Add at the top of `a.rb`

```
require_relative 'my_module'
```

if these files are in the same folder (or correct path to the file if not)